# Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^n}~dx = 1$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

I need help proving the following limit: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^n}~dx = 1$$

In WolframAlpha I was playing around with the values of the sequence defined by the integral and noticed that the values seem to get arbitrarily close to 1. I guess the difficulty is finding a closed expression for the value of the definite integral.

Comment: Try using Dominated Convergence theorem.

Comment: If $n$ is a positive even integer you should be able to evaluate the integral using complex analysis.

Comment: A plot of the integrand with a large $n$ shows you that the function tends to a square.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Break it into two integrals, on $[0,1]$ and on $[1,\infty)$.
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{1+x^n}<\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x^n}=\frac1{n-1}$$
so
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{1+x^n}\to0.$$
Also
$$1-\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x^n}=\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}\,dx
<\int_0^1 x^n\,dx=\frac1{n+1}\to0$$
so
$$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x^n}\to1.$$

Comment: Quite good :). I'm just so used to use the dominated convergence theorem that I didn't try doing with standard techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Split the integral in two parts, one in $[0,1]$ and the second one in $[1,+\infty]$. Using the Dominated convergence theorem you should conclude that the first integral converges to $1$ and the second one to $0$. If you need more help let me know.

Answer (score 1):

For $x \le 1$ we have $x^{n+1} \le x^n$ so $\frac{1}{1+x^{n}} \le \frac1{1+x^{n+1}}$ so using the Lebesgue Monotone Convergence theorem we get

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0,1]}\frac{dx}{1+x^n} = \int_{[0,1]}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^n}\right)\,dx = \int_{[0,1]} dx = 1$$

For $x \ge 1$ and $n \ge 2$ we have $\frac{1}{1+x^n} \le \frac{1}{x^n} \le \frac1{x^2}$ which is integrable on $[1, +\infty)$ so using the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem we get

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[1, +\infty)}\frac{dx}{1+x^n} = \int_{[1 ,+\infty)}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^n}\right)\,dx = \int_{[1, +\infty)} 0 \,dx = 0$$

Therefore

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0, +\infty)}\frac{dx}{1+x^n}  =1$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

The integral

$$ \mathcal{I}= \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^n} dx,$$

can be equivalently expressed as

$$ \mathcal{I} = \frac{1}{n} \int^1_0  t^{\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right) - 1} \left(1-t\right)^{\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-1} dt = \frac{1}{n} B \left(1-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n} \right),$$

where $B(x,y)$ is the Beta function. You can then make use of the identity

$$ B(x,y) = \frac{\Gamma(x) \Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)} = \frac{\Gamma\left( 1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{n} \right)}{\Gamma(1)}, $$

where $\Gamma$ denotes the Gamma function and $\Gamma(1) = 1$. It can be shown that

$$ \Gamma\left( 1 - \frac{1}{n}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{n} \right) = \frac{\pi}{ \sin(\pi/n)}. $$

Hence, the integral takes the form

$$ \mathcal{I}= \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^n} dx = \left( \frac{\pi}{n} \right) \frac{1}{\sin(\pi/n)},$$

where the limit follows immediately.

---

The integral is obtained following the substitution

$$ t = \frac{1}{1+x^n}, $$

and making use of the fact

$$ dx = -\frac{1}{n} \left(\frac{1}{t(1-t)} \right) \left( \frac{1-t}{t}\right)^{1/n} dt.$$

Answer (score 0):

The integral has the value

$$\frac{\pi  \csc \left(\frac{\pi }{n}\right)}{n}$$

and the limit for $n \to \infty$ goes to $1$, where you can use l'Hospital's rule.

Comment: Well how'd you get that value?

Comment: Using the beta function. @MilesDavis

Comment: I think you must use some tricky substitution.

Comment: @MilesDavis One way to evaluate the integral is to use contour integration with a wedge (pie-shaped) contour.  A second methodology that uses real analysis only begins with the substitution $x\mapsto x^{1/n}$, recognizing of the resulting Beta function, using the relationship between Beta and Gamma functions, and exploiting the reflection property of the Gamma function.

Comment: @MilesDavis  Alternatively $$\int_0^1 \frac{1+x^{n-2}}{1+x^n}\,dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \left(\frac{1}{nk+1}+\frac{1}{nk+n-1}\right)$$which approaches $1$ as $n\to \infty$

Answer (score 0):

Note that we can write for $n>1$

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^n}\,dx&=\int_0^1 \frac{1+x^{n-2}}{1+x^n}\,dx\\\\
&=1+\int_0^1 \frac{x^{n-2}-x^n}{1+x^n}\,dx
\end{align}$$

and

$$\left|\int_0^1 \frac{x^{n-2}-x^n}{1+x^n}\,dx\right|\le \frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n+1}$$

Comment: Would the anonymous down voter care to comment?

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. If this answer is not useful, then I am happy to delete it.   Would you please let me know?

Comment: Hi Wesley.  Would you please let me know how I can improve my answer?  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  If this was not useful, I am happy to delete it.  Looking forward to your reply.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: And feel free to up vote any answer you found was useful - as you see fit of course. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the contour $[r,R], [R,Re^{\frac {2\pi}{n}i}], [Re^{\frac {2\pi}{n}i},re^{\frac {2\pi}{n}i}],[Re^{\frac {2\pi}{n}i}, r]$

$\displaystyle \int r^R f(x)\ dx + \int_0^{e^{\frac{2\pi}{n}i}}  f(Re^{it})Rie^{it}\ dt +\int{R}^r f(e^{\frac{2\pi}{n}i}x)e^{\frac{2\pi}{n}}\ dx + \int_{e^{\frac{2\pi}{n}i}}^0  f(re^{it})rie^{it}\ dt = \oint_\gamma f(z)\ dz$

$\displaystyle\lim_\limits{R\to\infty}\int_0^{e^{\frac{2\pi}{n}i}}  f(Re^{it})Rie^{it}\ dt = 0\\
\lim_\limits{r\to0}\int_{e^{\frac{2\pi}{n}i}}^0  f(re^{it})rie^{it}\ dt = 0$

$\displaystyle I - e^{\frac{2\pi}{n}i}I = \oint_\gamma f(z)\ dz$

There is one pole inside the contour.

$\oint_\gamma f(z)\ dz = 2\pi i(\frac {-e^{\frac{\pi}{n}i}}{n})\\
I =  \frac {2 i }{n(e^{\frac{\pi}{n}i}- e^{-\frac{\pi}{n}i})} = \pi\frac {\csc \frac {\pi}{n}}{n}$